# AngularJS router-ui resolve exception

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have following parent route in my app:

```
        .state('app',{
            url: '/app',
            templateUrl: 'views/app.html',
            resolve: loadSequence('modernizr','moment'),
            abstract: true,
            css:['assets/css/theme-1.css'],
            resolve: {
                loginRequired: loginRequired
            }

        })
```

The resolve is set at parent, so all the child will inherit the `loginRequired`. How can I set an exception to one of child from parent where `loginRequired` can be ignored. Following are my child route.

```
.state('app.passwordreset',{
                url: '/app/reset/:token',
                templateUrl: 'views/app_resetpass.html',
                resolve: loadSequence('modernizr','moment','resetCtrl'),
                css:['assets/css/theme-1.css']

            })
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is by inserting an intermediary state that only takes care of the login resolve. For example:

```
.state('app', { ... })
.state('app.restricted', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '',
    template: '<div ui-view=""></div>',
    resolve: {
        loginRequired: loginRequired
    }
})
.state('app.restricted.somechild', { ... })
.state('app.passwordreset', { ... });
```

This way, any child that requires authentication just needs to insert `app.restricted` before the state name. You essentially decouple the resolve requirement from the `app` parent state, making it able to be applied as necessary.